# Highlighted item changes position when scrolling listview

Tags: android, listview

Highlighted item changes position when scrolling listview. If i choose first item in listview and scrolling to the end, between every 7-8 item is selected. And even highlighted item lose its position and highlighting 3rd item. i dont use custom adapter for listview, only for textview. Here is code:

```
lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myadaptersong = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_item, R.id.menu, music);
    lv.setAdapter(myadaptersong);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(menuItem != null) menuItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            menuItem = view;
            menuItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a2aed3"));


    });
}
```

UPDATE:
Custom Adapter is this

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String music[];
int flag[];
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[]music, int []flag)
{
    this.music=music;
    this.flag=flag;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater.from(context));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return music.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item,viewGroup,false);
    TextView name= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu);
    name.setText(music[position]);


    return view;
}
```

}

what should i do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted won't work the way you intend (as you already noticed). Let's say your ListView shows 4 items on screen and you clicked on the first item (item 0, highlighting it by changing its background color). When you scroll down to see more views and item 0 goes off the screen, the view from item 0 will be recycled to show a later item (say, item 6).

Now item 6 is using the view whose background color you already changed, so it will be highlighted. As the view continues to go off-screen and be re-used, other random rows in the ListView will be highlighted.

You will need to implement a custom adapter to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. Now i created new custom adapter, now item highlighting but when scrolling up and then back to selected item, highlighted disappear. But items highlights gone already. i edited my question

Comment: Now you could do something like call `adapter.highlightedPosition = position;` (add an int to the adapter called `highlightedPosition`) to save the highlighted position in the adapter, and in `getView` select the color based on whether `position == highlightedPosition`